# Git submodules and Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, git-submodules

Our project has several submodules that contain code from other projects and these are embedded in our project.

I opted to use Eclipse CDT (rather than another IDE that isn't very bright) to edit my code.  The problem is that there are several modules that don't quite work right.  For example, a global search seems to see there is code based in the base module and embedded, but also it seems to see other projects (i.e. the submodules) where I get the same hits.  Example:

[image]

The root project is sensor-galaxy-survey-lcopc-tvoc, it includes submodule directory sensor-galaxy-survey, which includes submodule sensor-galaxy-platform.  A search now lists a hit in sensor-galaxy-platform as being duplicated in all 3 levels.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse (or is it CDT) to not duplicate it's searching through each submodule?  Eclipse sees each submodule as a separate build (which I think it should), but search and a few other features (like rename) seem to get duplicates.  Ever see what a rename of a method name that is duplicated does?  It's not pretty.